# Is there a better way to fill an array within a forEach loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

As I am fairly new to javascript, I can't create and fill my array 'data' the way I'd like to :

```
var data = new Array();
var i = 0;

results.forEach(function(lake) {
    var data[i] = [{
        name: lake.name,
        fishs: lake.fisheryType,
        dist: lake.distance,
        lat: lake.latitude,
        long: lake.longitude
    }, ];
    i++;
});
```

Here is the console.log of result:

```
[Object, Object] 0: Object 1: Object length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
```

When executing this code, I get

```
unexpected ] at line var data [i] = ...
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You'd like to fill the array with results.length clones of the same object?

Comment: I think you get the error because of the trailing `,` after `}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `map` method to create an array this way.  Each value returned by the callback is inserted into the array.

```
var data = results.map(function (lake) {
    return {
        name: lake.name,
        fishs: lake.fisheryType,
        dist: lake.distance,
        lat: lake.latitude,
        long: lake.longitude
    }
});
```